# Server reboot on Linux VM - Alert rule

Tags: azure, logging, analytics, monitor

I'm looking to create an alert rule in Azure Monitor to detect server reboots on Linux VMs. I have one for server reboots on Windows VMs, but I cannot find how to detect this on Linux.

I tried searching on the signals available but could not find anything. It seems as the only possibility is a log query.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking to create an alert rule in Azure Monitor to detect server reboots on Linux VMs.

To create an alert when the Linux server restarts, you can follow the steps below.

1. **Go to Azure Monitor > Logs > execute the below KQL query**

```kotlin
    AzureActivity
    | where ResourceProvider == "Microsoft.Compute" 
    | where OperationName == "Restart Virtual Machine" and ActivityStatus == "Succeeded"
    | extend VMName = extract("([^/]+$)", 1, tostring(ResourceId))
    | join kind=inner (
        Heartbeat
        | where OSType contains "Linux"
        | extend ComputerName = tostring(split(Computer, ".")[0])
        | project ComputerName, OSType
    ) on $left.VMName == $right.ComputerName
    | project TimeGenerated,OSType,VMName,OperationName,ActivityStatus,ResourceGroup,Caller
```

**Response:**

[image]

2. Click on **New Alert rule > create an alert rule**

[image]

3. Create an `action group`, or select an existing one if it has already been created.

[image]

4. Configure the **alert rule** as per your requirement.

[image]

5. You will receive an alert when the Linux server restarts.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting no results with your query. I have a Log Analytics WS with two Linux VMs connected for testing (using data collection rule and Azure Monitor Linux agents).

I am getting heartbeats and performance metrics in the WS, so they seem to be working fine, but the query doesn't return anything, even just trying to get "AzureActivity" results (generic) there is no output.

I followed step by step, but setting it up like show it triggers alerts every minute, as the condition is 1 or less than 1 results, since I am getting 0 it triggers alert every 1 min.

Comment: Please check any Activity Logs are created in Activity logs section in VM.

Comment: If still no result, kindly change the Time range, for ex:  Dec-01-2023 to Jan-09-2024.

Comment: Yes, the "Restart Virtual Machine" events appear in the Activity Log.

From the activity log there is an option to create an alert rule based on it, and it works, it sends an alert when the reboot is started, but the scope of the alert rule can only include VMs and I cannot modify the alert's severity. I rather have the Ws as scope of the alert rules as all my other alert rules centralized there.

Comment: Yes, if you create an alert from activity logs, you may need to select VMs. Instead of creating an alert from activity logs, create it from Monitor and use a KQL query, this will fetch all VMs that are matched to Query.

Comment: Yes, the problem with the query is the AzureActivity table does not show any results for me. It is strange because I can see the events in the activity logs of the VMs, but the AzureActivity table still does not return anything.

I'm trying out other options, like making an alert rule with the Uptime metric, it seems to work fine.

Comment: It will take some time to sync the logs to Azure Monitor,  still if it is not showing results, kindly  change the Time range to custom and select the date Nov:1:2023 to Today date and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256535/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-b-n-maldonado).