# How can i create an Azure alert when user logs into a VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to create an alert ie send an email as soon as anyone logs into an Azure Vm .

I have tried to create the alert but there is no "Sign In" alert.

How can i do this in Azure Portal ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i create an Azure alert when user logs into a VM?

To create an alert when a user logs into a VM, you can follow the steps below.

1. Navigate to the VM > Logs and enable the logs. Once the logs are enabled, it will take some time to synchronize them.
2. Run the below **KQL** query to fetch the `VM` Connected logs

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationName  == "Connect" and ActivityStatus =="Succeeded"
| extend ResourceIdParts = split(_ResourceId, "/")
| extend VMName = tostring(ResourceIdParts[8])
| project TimeGenerated, OperationName, ActivityStatus, Caller, CallerIpAddress, VMName
```

**Output:**

[image]

2. Create an alert configuration as per your requirement

[image]

3. Create an action group with required email.

[image]

4. You will receive an alert when you connect to `VM`.

[image]

Please refer to the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780518/server-reboot-on-linux-vm-alert-rule/77785124#77785124) I provided in my answer for a similar requirement.